# Como personalizar o CSS (tr:hover) em uma tabela com thead?

Tags: html5, css3

Eu estou criando um projeto para exercitar umas coisas, e fiz uma tabela com dados fictícios, onde, ao passar o mouse, a linha correspondente muda de cor. Só que eu não queria que isso acontecesse com a linha de título.
O que eu posso fazer?
Tentei de tudo mas não deu certo.

HTML:

```
<table id="esttt">
<thead>
<tr><td colspan="2">DADOS</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>ABC</td>
<td>22.7%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>DEF</td>
<td>42.5%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>GHI</td>
<td>12%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>JKL</td>
<td>54.6%</td>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

E O CSS:

```
#esttt{
    width:300px;
}

#esttt tr{
    line-height:30px;
}

#esttt tr:hover{
    background:#6B6BB6;
    color:#FFF;
}

#esttt thread{
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#esttt thread:hover{
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: Jovem o pessoal esta te negativado lá a sua pergunta não esta clara, tente no mínimo edita-la e colocar o código que vc ja tem até agora html/CSS isso vai ajudar para te dar uma resposta

Comment: editado. vc pode me ajudar agr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roberto primeiro veja que vc escreveu errado o nome do elemento no CSS... onde está `thread` deveria estar `thead`

Antes de mais nada achei a estrutura da sua tabela um pouco estranha... aqui vc pode ocnsultar a documentação da Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

O esperado seria algo tipo isso separando `thead` e `tbody`:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header content 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Body content 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Agora sobre o problema e para o `:hover` pegar em todas as `tr` menos na primeira vc pode usar o seletor `:not()` por exemplo e "retirar" da regra css apenas o primeiro `th` `(:first-child)` então ficara assim: `#esttt tr:not(:first-child):hover`

Veja como ficou o resultado com esse modelo usando o `:not()`:

```css
#esttt {
    width: 300px;
}

#esttt tr {
    line-height: 30px;
}

#esttt tr:not(:first-child):hover {
    background: #6B6BB6;
    color: #000;
}

#esttt thead {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#esttt thead:hover {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table id="esttt">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">DADOS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>22.7%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DEF</td>
            <td>42.5%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>GHI</td>
            <td>12%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>JKL</td>
            <td>54.6%</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: E se eu quisesse aplicar isso para qualquer outra linha da tabela?

Comment: @RobertoAraujo vc pode simplesmente declarar qual filho não vai receber usando o nth-child da própria regra tipo só a segunda não recebe: `tr:not(:nth-child(2)):hover` ou então fazer uma classe exclusiva pra TR que vc não que que receba o evento tipo: `<tr class="padrao essa-nao">DEF</tr>`

Comment: Ah ok. Justamente porque classe não funciona nesse caso. Já testei. Obrigado.

Comment: @RobertoAraujo se a resposta te ajudou de alguma forma e vc acha que a dúvida foi resolvida considere marcar a resposta como Aceita. Assim evitamos deixar no site perguntas já resolvidas, mas sem resposta aceita pendente.